# Retrieve Value of Arbitrary Button OnClick

Tags: jquery, html

My attempt

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-info">7</button>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('button').click(() => {
     console.log($(this));
     console.log($(this).html());
     console.log($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Desired result:

7

Comment: Oh that is probably my problem, I'm trying to use ES6 with Jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)**:

```
$(this).text()
```

```js
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
        console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-info">7</button>
```

Comment: I get undefined when I use that. EDIT: I was trying to use arrow functions with jquery. My bad. This works.

Comment: @ChasenBettinger Is there any difference between my snippet and your code? Did you wrap the click handler in document ready function?